# Syntax error when attempting to use SQLite query to create table in android

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite, syntax-error

I am trying to execute a String query but it is giving me a syntax error as shown:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Enter (_id INTEGER PRIMARY
>   KEY,_audio_id TEXT, )

I've checked multiple times with https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html and it matches but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. My query is as shown:

```
public void CreatePlaylist(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String query="CREATE TABLE "+ name +" (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_AUDIO_ID + " TEXT,"+
                " )";
                System.out.println("DB "+db);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove last comma:

```
public void CreatePlaylist(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String query="CREATE TABLE "+ name +" (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_AUDIO_ID + " TEXT"+              -- here
                " )";
                System.out.println("DB "+db);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Table name can contain spaces but you need to quote identifier with `"`. The good practice is to use avoid spaces in table/column names `"table name"` and use `tableName` or `table_name` instead.

Comment: Thanks it worked! So I suppose only the last column added doesn't need a comma? And the name of my table cannot have spaces?

Comment: @LewWeiHao See updated and yes, after last column do not use comma

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the colon from the end of this line:

```
COLUMN_AUDIO_ID + " TEXT,"

/*CREATE TABLE name ( 
    COLUMN_ID + INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    COLUMN_AUDIO_ID + TEXT 
);*/
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `" TEXT,"`  to  `" TEXT "` . You should not have a comma after `TEXT`.